# openshift: my local gears often timeout and go down which cause response time very long

Tags: performance, timeout, response, openshift, layer

my application is a scalable tomcat application with MySQL. If I do not access my application for a while, response time is very long when I access it again. Checking haproxy.log:

`[WARNING] 131/134600 (449836) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10002ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[WARNING] 131/134644 (449836) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 4068ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 131/154052 (449836) : Server express/gear-5370cea0500446741d00058b-ibrainext is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10004ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[WARNING] 131/154323 (449836) : Server express/gear-5370cea0500446741d00058b-ibrainext is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 501ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 131/154550 (449836) : Server express/gear-5370cea0500446741d00058b-ibrainext is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10003ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[WARNING] 131/154643 (449836) : Server express/gear-5370cea0500446741d00058b-ibrainext is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 7ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 131/182346 (449836) : Server express/gear-5370cea0500446741d00058b-ibrainext is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10003ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[WARNING] 131/182512 (449836) : Server express/gear-5370cea0500446741d00058b-ibrainext is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 11ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 131/194433 (449836) : Server express/gear-5370cea0500446741d00058b-ibrainext is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10004ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[WARNING] 131/194439 (449836) : Server express/gear-5370cea0500446741d00058b-ibrainext is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 109ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 131/194615 (449836) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10002ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[WARNING] 131/194735 (449836) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 0ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.`

Look like the timeout value is 10sec.  How can I keep my application running without going down ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not access your application for 24 hours, it will get idled (if this is a free acount), and depending on how large your application is, it could take awhile to spin back up when you do access it again.

Comment: only idle for around 10 minutes, not 24 hours. also I upgraded to Bronze plan weeks ago.  Thanks for help though.

Comment: Just looked at haproxy.cfg(for load-balance).  There are some timeout values which matches the values in the log.  So I am going to change those timeout and see if that would help.

Comment: changing the timeout values in haproxy.cfg does prevent local gears from going down. But response time is still too long,50 sec on average, if application idle for about 10 minutes. I will move my application to other hosting site if situation does not change here in two weeks.

Comment: Are you doing lots of processing on the page you are trying to access?  You are using a small gear on the free plan correct?  You might need a bigger gear, maybe having memory issues

Comment: No, my application is  simple. no lot of processing.  I just notice this afternoon that the response time is improved a lot. I used 'top' unix command to look at memory allocation.  It is 2gb free instead of 45mg free before.  So I think the issue is the memory allocation.

Comment: Add to my last comment.  System has to have enough free memory available. Otherwise if my app is not accessed in minutes, it will be swapped out of memory to disk.  It takes time to swapped back into memory.

Comment: i have noticed similar problems. Site just crashes and I get a 503. I have had to re-deploy a few times/week. I have no traffic. My thought is the free plan won't even sustain the constant pings from haproxy. I'm certainly not going to pay money for this.